# Is there a way to set a default controller in symfony when no controller is found?

Tags: symfony, routes

When the controller given for a route is somehow invalid(doesn't exist or is not callable) symfony throws an `InvalidArgumentException` saying "Controller Foo\BarController::bazAction for URI /foo/bar is not callable" I want to forward these to a default controller, How can I do that?

Comment: Use kernel event `CONTROLLER` http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html example

Comment: @skowron-line's approach will work.  An alternative is to simply define a route which matches everything.